# How to reduce image size in sweave?

Tags: sweave

How to reduce image size in sweave?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\title{Sweave Example 1}
\author{Friedrich Leisch}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

In this example we embed parts of the examples from the
\texttt{kruskal.test} help page into a \LaTeX{} document:

<<>>=
data(airquality)
library(ctest)
kruskal.test(Ozone ~ Month, data = airquality)
@
which shows that the location parameter of the Ozone 
distribution varies significantly from month to month. Finally we
include a boxplot of the data:

\begin{center}
<<fig=TRUE,echo=FALSE>>=
boxplot(Ozone ~ Month, data = airquality) ## reduce image size so that can fit in window.
@
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Regards

Comment: May I suggest that you use a different example - `library( ctest )` is not supported anymore in R 2.15. May I also suggest that you paste your sample code in a way that it can be used without major editing / re-formatting?  --  Possibly, something like `<<fig=true,width=6,height=4>>=` can help (see Ross Ihaka, "Customizing Sweave" )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [knitr](http://yihui.name/knitr/) instead Sweave. See `out.width` and `out.height` [options](http://yihui.name/knitr/options#chunk_options).

Your example would look like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\title{Sweave Example 1}
\author{Friedrich Leisch}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

In this example we embed parts of the examples from the
\texttt{kruskal.test} help page into a \LaTeX{} document:

<<>>=
data(airquality)
library(ctest)
kruskal.test(Ozone ~ Month, data = airquality)
@
which shows that the location parameter of the Ozone 
distribution varies significantly from month to month. Finally we
include a boxplot of the data:

<<plot,fig.align="center",out.width="0.8\\linewidth",echo=FALSE>>=
boxplot(Ozone ~ Month, data = airquality) ## reduce image size so that can fit in window.
@

\end{document}
```