# Change the width of a figure created with barplot()

Tags: r, bar-chart, sweave

When I use `barplot`, I cannot see the names of the bars if the names are too big. For example:

```
barplot(as.numeric(c(2, 4, 1, 6)), col = c("lightblue"), main="Barplot",
        names.arg=c("This is bar 1...1", "This is bar 1...2",
                    "This is bar 1...3", "This is bar 1...4"), 
        xpd=TRUE, las=1, lwd=1, cex.names=0.5)
```

When I use `horiz=TRUE`, I cannot see the names on the left:

```
barplot(as.numeric(c(2, 4, 1, 6)), col = c("lightblue"), main="Barplot", 
        names.arg=c("This is \nbar 2...1", "This is bar 2...2",
                    "This is bar 2...3", "This is bar 2...4"), 
        xpd=TRUE, las=1, lwd=1, horiz=TRUE, space=1)
```

Using a line break in names (e.g. "This is \nbar 2...1") or reducing text size with, e.g., `cex.names=0.5` "solves" the problem but I would prefer to add space so that the names fit.

Is there any ability to change the width of the whole figure including the plot?

Comment: Take a look at the entries for `mar` and `oma` in `?par`

Comment: par(mar=c(5, 20, 4, 2)), Using in R Sweave does not work.

Comment: Thank you it works executing in R Sweave document previously
 
par(mar=c(5, 20, 4, 2)) then barplot(...)

Comment: For the first bar plot I have not any solution yet. Using parameter width during barplot(...,  width=c(1,5,1,5), ...) does not work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When `horiz=FALSE` (the default), one option is to plot the bar names perpendicular to the x-axis with `las=2`, and add height to the bottom margin to accommodate the length of the names. To add space to the margin, use `par(mar=c(b, l, t, r))`, where `b`, `l`, `t`, and `r` are numbers giving the number of lines width/height that you want the bottom, left, top, and right margins to be, respectively.

For example:

```
par(mar=c(15, 3, 3, 1)) # 15 line height for bottom margin
barplot(c(2, 4, 1, 6), main="Barplot", las=2,
        names.arg=c("This is my first very long name",
                    "This is my second very long name",
                    "This is my third very long name",
                    "This is my fourth very long name"))
```

[image]

When `horiz=TRUE`, you can use `las=1` and add space to the left margin instead:

```
par(mar=c(3, 15, 3, 1))
barplot(c(2, 4, 1, 6), main="Barplot", las=1, horiz=TRUE,
        names.arg=c("This is my first very long name",
                    "This is my second very long name",
                    "This is my third very long name",
                    "This is my fourth very long name"))
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know any method to change the width of the plotted figure. I think `pin` or `plt` would do that. But the two parameters `pin` and `plt` of fct. par() I dont understand.

Comment: @b4154 - If I understand what you are trying to do, maybe you just need to increase the width of your plotting device. E.g. if you're plotting to an `x11/quartz` device, then just drag the left/right handles. If you're plotting to an RStudio graphics device, increase the width of the pane. If you're plotting to, e.g., a png, then increase the `width`.

Comment: I think the pane width has to be changed because it will be executed in R Sweave doc to produce PDF. How to change the pane width? Could not find yet

Comment: @b4154 - you should search existing posts for changing width of plots in Sweave (e.g. [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4495881/489704)). [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14110998/489704) and [this](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2003-October/040073.html) are probably also relevant.

Answer (score 0):

when you `Export` you can adjust width and height
[image]